# Tkinter Loop Never Exits Cleanly

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, event-loop

Python 2.7

I have written a `run` method for my Tkinter GUI rather than using the standard `mainloop`, and it always exits on an error when I close the window, even after implementing a `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol as advised elsewhere on SO.  I tried invoking `exit` in the protocol callback and `return`ing from the loop, but Python always goes through the loop one last time.  Why is this?

```
class FrameApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.rootWin.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback_destroy)
        self.winRunning = False

    def callback_destroy(self):
        self.winRunning = False
        self.rootWin.destroy() # go away, window
        exit() # GET OUT
```

Here is the run loop:

```
    def run(self):
        last = -infty
        self.winRunning = True
        ...
        while self.winRunning:
            # 4.a. Calc geometry
            self.calcFunc( self.get_sliders_as_list() )
            # 4.b. Send new coords to segments
            self.simFrame.transform_contents()
            # 4.d. Wait remainder of 40ms
            elapsed = time.time() * 1000 - last
            if elapsed < 40:
                time.sleep( (40 - elapsed) / 1000.0 )
            # 4.e. Mark beginning of next loop
            last = time.time() * 1000
            # 4.f. Update window
            if not self.winRunning: # This does not solve the problem 
                return # still tries to call 'update', 
                #        and never exits cleanly
            self.canvas.update() 
            # don't know how to prevent these from being called 
            # again after the window is destroyed
            self.rootWin.update_idletasks()
```

Result:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 972, in
>   update_idletasks
>       self.tk.call('update', 'idletasks')
>   _tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed

Comment: Why are you not using tkinter's `mainloop`?

Comment: I'm not using it because I have some calcs to do outside of the loop (`self.calcFunc`, in the file that instantiates the `FrameApp`) and they aren't yet heavy enough to have their own thread. ~ I'm trying to make this modular so that a `FrameApp` can run any `calcFunc` that gets assigned to it.

Comment: Your loop need break internaly (so if finished), how to manage all flags ? Meaning `while True : if my_end_signal occured : break`. Detect `end point` before destroy everthing !

Comment: You can see that there is an `if not self.winRunning` clause within the loop. When the running flag property is set to false by the window destroy protocol, it is supposed to break the loop.  I have tried both `return` and `break` as a response to an exit flag, but I get the same error in both cases.

Comment: I'm invoking the script directly from the terminal with `python FILENAME.py`.  My usual IDE, Spyder, will sometimes cause many windows to be created if I launch a Tkinter script from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the mainloop, tkinter cannot get the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` message to call your exit function. (Or rather, it can only catch anything during the ~millisecond of the `update_idletasks` call, as it won't queue since tkinter doesn't have an event loop (and thus queue) going since you never start one.) It can't catch signals if it can't communicate with the Window Manager (system), and it can't communicate if it isn't looping.

To solve it, just use the event/main loop. Make your `run` function save any state it needs and call itself `after` whatever interval you wish.

---

On another note, don't use `time.sleep` with tkinter- it prevents it from doing anything (and also the 40ms remaining of sleep is probably longer than the rest of the loop, so you'd have 41 ms of waiting and 0.5 ms of clickability). Instead, just carefully configure your `root.after` statements (you can calculate things in them, too)

Comment: Do you mean something of this flavor?
`def tick(self):
    calcTime = remaining_t() ;
    root.after( calcTime , self.tick )`

Comment: Something exactly along those lines. It could even be `def tick(self): root.after(remaining_t(), self.tick)` ; there's no need to store an intermediate variable if it isn't used elsewhere.

Comment: This solved it!  I wasn't aware of the `after` method for the Tkinter window. ~ The two solutions I had come across were packing all the calcs in a widget callback (ugly) or running the calcs in a separate thread (too much work for a toy script).